# How to turn off kohana's string sanitisation temporarily

Tags: php, kohana

I'm building a dynamic form in Kohana and notice that it is doing the following:

```
 echo "'";
```

results in

```
&#039;
```

in the output instead of a literal ' character.

I suspect its xss_clean getting in the way which is normally a good thing, but if I want to avoid it I have to code differently when I need a literal ' output to the page.

e.g.

```
echo form::input($id"['did'", $did);
```

results in output looking like.

```
<input type="text" name="1[&#039;did&#039;]" value="12345" />
```

Comment: Why would you include quotes in the form element name? Using `1[did]` would work just fine.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't using them but thought they were required for IE as I was getting an error on them.  But it turns out I was looking at the wrong line number.  doh!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the HTML class code you'll notice that all attributes are generated with `HTML::attributes()`, which makes all vars go through `htmlspecialchars()`.

( This should have been HTML::chars(),  one more thing to report at kohana dev lol ).

This is done in order to make elements generated with kohana HTML class valid.
If you really want to make it invalid, write it as it's outputted without using the HTML class.

Comment: Looks like this is the only option.  Makes the HTML classes fairly useless when you have only slightly complex needs.